# Setting a checkbox checked if db value is 1 and unchecked if db value is 0

Tags: php, yii

what parameters to add in my code?

```
$form->checkBox($model,'ATTRIBNAME',array("id"=>"mybox"));?>
```

i wanna display the checkbox as checked if the value from the db is 1
and unchecked if the value it got from the db is 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add checked attribute

```
if ($value==1) {$attrs=array("id"=>"mybox","checked"=>"checked");}
if ($value==0) {$attrs=array("id"=>"mybox");}
$form->checkBox($model,'ATTRIBNAME',$attrs);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the value of `$model->ATTRIBNAME=1`  then `$form->checkBox(...)` method automatically check the checkbox, 0 for uncheck

```
$model->ATTRIBNAME = 1;  // 0 for uncheck

//Now it displays checked box
$form->checkBox($model,'ATTRIBNAME',array("id"=>"mybox"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Small code

```
$form->checkBox($model,'ATTRIBNAME',array("id"=>"mybox","checked"=>($value==1)?"checked":""));
```